# Accessing a cookie set in template using document.cookie in a django View

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, cookies

I'm trying to use a cookie to store an integer value which will then be used to determine the range of data to be displayed on the next page.

I am currently using the function

```
document.cookie="name=tom"
```

I've checked my browser storage and the cookie is stored there.

And trying to access the cookie via a django view using

```
request.COOKIES['name']
```

which is unsuccessful.

I'm new to django so any info on why this doesn't work and best practice ways of managing variables between js and Python would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to obtain that after the browser made a *new* HTTP request?

Comment: Yes - is this not possible then?